# Science Fiction Planetarium Show

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to figure out the title of a computer animated planetarium show that I watched about 7 to 12 years ago at the Reading Planetarium. The story is about a teenage girl and a robot on some escape ship where a scientific expedition was observing a supernova. They have to retrieve resources and view several astronomical phenomenon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be *[Dark Star Adventure](http://statemuseumpa.org/planetarium/group-shows/)*?

[image: Movie Poster]

> This animated adventure lets us join a mischievous girl who is bored by science as she takes an unforgettable voyage of discovery. Along the way you will witness the power of a supernova, explore the heart of a gaseous nebula, visit an exotic pulsar, and learn about black holes. All to help find her way back to her home planet.

**Trailer**

[Educator's Guide](http://statemuseumpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/educ_guide_darkstar.pdf)